# Get top 10 records from sp

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a sp and I need to get top 10 record from sp.

Here is my effort,

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(id INT,Name VARCHAR(20),Phone VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Temp
EXEC sp_MyListReport
@id, @Name , @Phone
SELECT TOP(10) * FROM @Temp
```

@id, @Name , @Phone are parameters for sp, but it is not showing any records.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you  run `sp_MyListReport` with the same parameters  - does it returns anything?

Comment: Yes, its returning more records, so I need to display only top 10 records

Comment: Is it returning any error. Try executing as batch instead with ; after proc. And, what are the output columns of sp_MyListReport. It should have equal number of o/p columns as target

Comment: Its not giving any error and sp has equal no of o/p columns as (id, Name,Phone)

Comment: Hello ajay ,can you share the records at the first row returned by your stored procedure _sp_MyListReport_?

Comment: You want Top 10 records. So you want it to be in Top order for column- id ? In ascending order or descending order ?